# Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: connection refused on DDEV (docker) setup in drupal while running phpunit functional javascript tests

Tags: phpunit, port, drupal-8, ddev

> The test wasn't able to connect to your webdriver instance. For more
>   information read core/tests/README.md.
>
> The original message while starting Mink: Could not open connection:
>   Curl error thrown for http POST to
>   `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session with params:
>   {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","name":"Behat
>   Test","chromeOptions":{"w3c":false}}}`
>
> Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused
>
> ```
> /var/www/html/core/tests/Drupal/FunctionalJavascriptTests/WebDriverTestBase.php:64
> /var/www/html/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php:409
> /var/www/html/core/modules/system/tests/src/FunctionalJavascript/System/DateFormatTest.php:29
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a container with the chromedriver, Please see the ddev-contrib PR about [adding chromedriver example](https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/pull/75). It also has a reference to the excellent article by Matt Glaman, https://glamanate.com/blog/running-drupals-functionaljavascript-tests-ddev

Please note that your configuration won't want to access the chromedriver at *localhost*, because it's not running on the localhost (the web container). It's running in the chromedriver container.